# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in JQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 Application, I am using JQuery datepicker for the Dynamic Form Input

when you click add(+) button, it adds array of controls.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th scope="col">Start Date<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
     <th scope="col">End Date<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
     <th scope="col" width="8%"><a class="btn btn-info addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
   </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
    <td>
       <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="start_date[]" class="form-control data-datepicker">
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="end_date[]" class="form-control data-datepicker">
    </td>
 </tbody>
 </thead>
</table>


<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('body').on('focus',"[data-datepicker]", function(){
             $(this).datepicker({
                     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                     changeMonth: true,
                     changeYear: true,     
                     showAnim: 'slideDown',
                     duration: 'fast',                    
                     yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear(),
             });
    });​           
 });
</script>       

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
   var isHod = {{ Auth::user()->is_hod == 0 ? 0 : 1 }};
    var numRows = $('.activity').length

    if (numRows<4) {
        addRow();
    }
        });

        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
' <td><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span></div><input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="start_date[]" class="form-control data-datepicker"></div></td>\n' +
' <td><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span></div><input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="end_date[]" class="form-control data-datepicker"></div></td>\n' +
' <td><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
' </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
    addRemoveListener();
});

function addRemoveListener() {
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
        var l =$('tbody tr').length;
        if(l==1){
            alert('you cant delete last one')
        }else{

            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        }

    });
 }

</script>
```

The default JQuery datepicker works fine. But when I clicked on the Add new (+) to add new ones on array. When I click on the start_date and end_date, no date was coming.

I got this error on the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

And this line was highlighted:

[image: datepicker error]

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the comma after getFullYear()

Comment: @JaphethSuarez - I did that, but still have the same issue

Comment: Can you give me the link where you got jquery datepicker? I'll try checking it out.

Comment: @JaphethSuarez AdminLTE3  plugins   https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/releases/tag/v3.0.5    I am using adminlte3 template

Comment: If you still can't make it work, try using a different datepicker. jQuery datepicker is one of them. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. Really hard to use a plugin that's already included in a template